# The regex "\|\|" in OCaml incorrectly matches the string ";;"

Tags: regex, match, ocaml

I am using Str.regexp in OCaml to detect double semicolons or or and and symbols among other things, but a lot of the regexes aren't working as intended. For example,

```
Str.string_match (Str.regexp "\|\|") ";;" 0
```

returns true. You have to escape a character like '|', so I used "\|\|" as my regex instead of "||". However, I heard you might have to escape twice and write "\\|\\|" in Ocaml, yet this did not work either. So what am I supposed to do? [Rubular](https://rubular.com/) thinks the Regex should work, but this is Ocaml and not Ruby, so I might've missed some subtle language difference.

Comment: By the way, the argument to `Str.regexp` is a regular OCaml string, and a backslash between double-quotes is interpreted by OCaml syntax itself. It turns out that the escape sequence with a pipe has no meaning in OCaml syntax, and that the compiler tolerates `"\|"` when you actually mean `"\\|"` (i.e. the 2-character string consisting of a backslash, then a pipe), but you get a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the regex

```
"||"
```

will work. Usually, '|' represents or and needs to be escaped to represent a literal bar, but it seems to be the opposite in Ocaml.

Comment: The Str regex syntax is closer to emacs syntax than the Ruby dialect you're looking at - pipe isn't the only thing that needs to be escaped to become important. Capturing parenthesis too. And it's missing a lot of features you might be used to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no (widely accepted) regex standard. And while many common conventions have emerged, every implementation is different. You should therefore always reference [the documentation of the implementation you're using](https://ocaml.org/api/Str.html).

If you want an implementation that provides more conventional syntax, however, I'd recommend [`ocaml-re`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re), which is a regex implementation in pure OCaml that offers a choice of several different syntaxes, Perl, Posix and Emacs as well as a subset of PCRE.